# How to select oldest rows from table where a value type does not exist?

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists

Suppose I have a table like this:

**Example data:**

```
x_id | type | user_id | other_id | date
----------------------------------------------
 123 |  AB  |   999   |    001   | 10/12/12
 124 |  CD  |   887   |    258   | 12/12/21
 125 |  CD  |   651   |    702   | 03/04/11
 126 |  AB  |   114   |    003   | 01/19/01
 127 |  EF  |   573   |    777   | 02/08/17
 128 |  AB  |   221   |    145   | 07/21/94
 129 |  CD  |   999   |    001   | 10/12/12
 130 |  CD  |   573   |    777   | 10/10/99
 131 |  EF  |   114   |    003   | 03/02/97
 132 |  EF  |   000   |    914   | 01/01/82
```

I want to select records with a `type` of `AB`, unless that type does not exist for a record. If that's the case, then I would want the oldest record, regardless of the `type`. For example, this is the result I'm looking for:

**Desired result:**

```
x_id | type | user_id | other_id | date
----------------------------------------------
123 |  AB  |   999   |    001   | 10/12/12
124 |  CD  |   887   |    258   | 12/12/21
125 |  CD  |   651   |    702   | 03/04/11
126 |  AB  |   114   |    003   | 01/19/01
128 |  AB  |   221   |    145   | 07/21/94
130 |  CD  |   573   |    777   | 10/10/99
132 |  EF  |   000   |    914   | 01/01/82
```

I started out by seeing if I could simply return records where the `type` of `AB` does not exist via the query below:

```
SELECT t1.x_id
,t1.type
,MAX(t1.user_id)
,t2.other_id
,MIN(t1.date)
FROM TBL_1 t1
LEFT JOIN TBL_2 t2 ON t1.y_id = t2.y_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TBL_1 t1a
WHERE t1.user_id = t1a.user_id
AND t1.type LIKE '%AB%'
)
GROUP BY t1.x_id, t1.type, t2.other_id
```

However, this even returns records where a `type` equal to `AB` exists. For example, `user_id: 999` has a `type` of `AB` *and* `CD`. So I wouldn't want the query to return `user_id: 999` since they have a `type` of `AB`:

```
 x_id | type | user_id | other_id | date
----------------------------------------------
 124 |  CD  |   887   |    258   | 12/12/21
 125 |  CD  |   651   |    702   | 03/04/11
 127 |  EF  |   573   |    777   | 02/08/17
 129 |  CD  |   999   |    001   | 10/12/12
 130 |  CD  |   573   |    777   | 10/10/99
 131 |  EF  |   114   |    003   | 03/02/97
 132 |  EF  |   000   |    914   | 01/01/82
```

What am I missing in this query to only return records that do not have a `type` of `AB`? And how can I further evolve this to select the oldest record regardless of type if `AB` does not exist? I'm not sure if I need to use a `CASE WHEN` or if there is a simpler way to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- step1: count total types per user
- step2: since ab is relevant we create a filter where we have only AB rows
- step3: getting the min() for each user regardless of the type
- step4: create another filter, with the condition to pick rows that doesn't have AB for any user_id and the date = minimum for that given user

```
with main as (

select 
*,
count(type) over(partition by user_id) as total_types_per_user
from main
),
filter_one as (
select
 * ,
case when total_types_per_user >=1 and type = 'AB' then true
else false end as is_relevant_one,

min(date) over(partition by user_id) as min_date_per_user

from main
),
filter_two as (

select
*,
case when NOT is_relevant_one and date = min_date_per_user then true
else false end as is_relevant_two,
from filter_one


)
select * from filter_two where is_relevant_one or is_relevant_two
```

Answer (score 0):

With sample data from the question,

```sql
WITH
    tbl (X_ID, A_TYPE, A_USER_ID, OTHER_ID, A_DATE) AS
        (
            Select 123, 'AB', '999', '001', To_Date('10/12/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 124, 'CD', '887', '258', To_Date('12/12/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 125, 'CD', '651', '702', To_Date('03/04/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 126, 'AB', '114', '003', To_Date('01/19/2001', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 127, 'EF', '573', '777', To_Date('02/08/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 128, 'AB', '221', '145', To_Date('07/21/1994', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 129, 'CD', '999', '001', To_Date('10/12/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 130, 'CD', '573', '777', To_Date('10/10/1999', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 131, 'EF', '114', '003', To_Date('03/02/1997', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 132, 'EF', '000', '914', To_Date('01/01/1982', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual 
        ),
```

Create CTE (tbl_a) extending the rows with LISTAGG(A_TYPE) and MIN(A_DATE) analytic functions to use for filtering the rows.

```sql
  tbl_a AS
    (
        Select t.*,
               LISTAGG(t.A_TYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By t.A_TYPE) OVER(Partition By t.A_USER_ID) "TYPES",
               CASE WHEN Min(t.A_DATE) OVER(Partition By t.A_USER_ID) = t.A_DATE THEN 'Y' END "OLDEST_USR"
        From   tbl t
    )
/*
      X_ID A_TYPE A_USER_ID OTHER_ID A_DATE    TYPES                OLDEST_USR
---------- ------ --------- -------- --------- -------------------- ----------
       132 EF     000       914      01-JAN-82 EF                   Y          
       126 AB     114       003      19-JAN-01 AB, EF                          
       131 EF     114       003      02-MAR-97 AB, EF               Y          
       128 AB     221       145      21-JUL-94 AB                   Y          
       130 CD     573       777      10-OCT-99 CD, EF               Y          
       127 EF     573       777      08-FEB-17 CD, EF                          
       125 CD     651       702      04-MAR-11 CD                   Y          
       124 CD     887       258      12-DEC-21 CD                   Y          
       123 AB     999       001      12-OCT-12 AB, CD               Y          
       129 CD     999       001      12-OCT-12 AB, CD               Y         
*/
```

Now there are columns TYPES and OLDEST_USR (in every row) that we can use to fiter the data...

```sql
SELECT    a.X_ID, a.A_TYPE, a.A_USER_ID, a.OTHER_ID, a.A_DATE
FROM      tbl_a a
WHERE     (a.A_TYPE = 'AB') OR ( a.TYPES NOT LIKE('%AB%') AND OLDEST_USR = 'Y')
ORDER BY  a.X_ID
/*  R e s u l t :
      X_ID A_TYPE A_USER_ID OTHER_ID A_DATE  
---------- ------ --------- -------- ---------
       123 AB     999       001      12-OCT-12 
       124 CD     887       258      12-DEC-21 
       125 CD     651       702      04-MAR-11 
       126 AB     114       003      19-JAN-01 
       128 AB     221       145      21-JUL-94 
       130 CD     573       777      10-OCT-99 
       132 EF     000       914      01-JAN-82
*/
```

... you can put the above CTE as a subquery in the FROM clause like below - the resul is the same ...

```sql
SELECT    a.X_ID, a.A_TYPE, a.A_USER_ID, a.OTHER_ID, a.A_DATE
FROM  ( Select t.*,
               SubStr(LISTAGG(t.A_TYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By t.A_TYPE) OVER(Partition By t.A_USER_ID), 1, 20) "TYPES",
               CASE WHEN Min(t.A_DATE) OVER(Partition By t.A_USER_ID) = t.A_DATE THEN 'Y' END "OLDEST_USR"
        From   tbl t    
      ) a
WHERE     (a.A_TYPE = 'AB') OR ( a.TYPES NOT LIKE('%AB%') AND OLDEST_USR = 'Y')
ORDER BY  a.X_ID
```